# React-dev-server doesn't refresh code

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router, create-react-app

I've stumbled against the issue that react-dev-server, when i alter code , the changes don't appear on the app itself (after refreshing, not hot-loading). I've tried this with setting up a project myself, or using Facebooks Create-react-app, which comes preconfigured, and should work out of the box.

The console doesn't return any errors, or warnings. So i'm quite lost at this point. Any help is appriciated!

Thanks!

Comment: can you show us some example code?

Comment: Like i mentioned above, it is using the default create-react-app code. More info can be found here: [link](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/07/22/create-apps-with-no-configuration.html)

Answer (score 0):

Update your node and npm version and restart your system. It should solve the issue.